# How to turn off session for only one non-mvc razor page?

Tags: asp.net, razor

In non-mvc web form pages, using the *.aspx file, you can specify the  EnableSessionState="false" to turn off the session.

But how you do that in non-mvc web app razor pages, using the *.cshtml file?   EnableSessionState is not an ojbect in razor.  :-(

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

EnableSessionState is for ASP.NET (Web Forms). (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306996) It's not available in ASP.NET MVC. 
Are you trying to disable the session in your ASP.NET MVC Web Site? Here's a good article about MVC and Sessions. http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/906b060113-Controlling-Session-Behavior-in-Asp.Net-MVC4.html

Comment: Saw that link from Google search but it's for MVC project.   I'm using non-MVC project (web application) where I got Razor components from NuGet (Microsoft.AspNet.Razor).